# Objectify doesn't store synchronously, even with now

Tags: google-app-engine, persistence, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

My servlet should perform the following : when a user registers at a venue, I check whether he's currently registered somewhere (even if it is the same venue) if so, unregister him and to register him once again. 
I have the following code, which I've simplified in order to show my problem :

```
    Date tempDate = new Date();


    Visit v = ofy().load().type(Visit.class)
            .filter(Visit.USER_ID, 5L)
            .filter(Visit.EXIT_DATE, null).first().get();

    if(v != null)
        exitVenue(5L, 7L, tempDate);

    Visit visit = new Visit(5L, 7L, tempDate);      
    ofy().save().entity(visit).now();

    Date tempDate2 = new Date();


    Visit v2 = ofy().load().type(Visit.class)
            .filter(Visit.USER_ID, 5L)
            .filter(Visit.EXIT_DATE, null).first().get();

    if(v2 != null)
        exitVenue(5L, 7L, tempDate2);

    Visit visit2 = new Visit(5L, 7L, tempDate2);        
    ofy().save().entity(visit2).now();
}


public void exitVenue(Long userID, Long venueID, Date exitDate) {

    Visit visit = ofy().load().type(Visit.class)
            .filter(Visit.USER_ID, userID)
            .filter(Visit.VENUE_ID, venueID)
            .filter(Visit.EXIT_DATE, null).first().get();

    if(visit == null){
        log.info("ERROR : User " + userID + " exited venue " + venueID + ", but Visit was not found");
        return;
    }
    visit.setExitDate(exitDate);

    ofy().save().entity(visit).now();
}
```

the problem is that when I preform all this operation for the second time, it not always finds that there is already a visit in the datastore (every second test, or so). And I'm confused isn't 'now()' suppose to store it right away and only then to continue running ?

Thank you very much for your help,
Dan

Comment: Note that if I run this with the debug tool, everything works fine. That's why I assumed it's a matter of speed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is happening because GAE Datastore is [eventually consistent](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency): when you create/update an entity, the method returns immediately, but [indexes are still being built asynchronously](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write). Since queries rely on indexes you do not see the changes immediately.

Also, this has nothing to do with objectify - this is a property of the underlying datastore. The synchronous write (`.now()`) waits for the *commit phase* to finish , while asynchronous returns immediately even before that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, two more questions : 1. Is there a way for me to do something with this, to speed up the transactions, or is it something I just need to take account of when designing my app? 2. I worked with GAE and JPA before and never noticed this, can this be?

Comment: I'm not sure why you didn't notice with JPA unless you were using the Master/Slave datastore then too (no longer available) which saved its indexes before returning from the Save call. There's nothing you can do to change this behaviour, you just need to take account of how it works.

Comment: Docs state that entity changes are applied (= indexes are written out) next time when read is executed: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write. Maybe you should try to issue a read after write.

Comment: Thank you Peter, but it didn't help. O.K. I guess i'll just change my design a bit.

Comment: You can work around this issue by adding a @parent to your datastore entity and use ancestor queries. Other thing, if you know the key and can do a get(), then you will not run into the eventual consistency either.

Comment: koma: sure - this mentioned in the links provided in answer. But @parent creates ancestor relationship and puts entities in the same entity group - this has some downsides, most notably entity group has write limit of 1 write/s.