# Objects not saving using Objectify and GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, loading, objectify

I'm trying to save an object and verify that it is saved right after, and it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is my object

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;

@Entity
public class PlayerGroup {
    @Id public String n;//sharks
    public ArrayList<String> m;//members [39393,23932932,3223]

}
```

Here is the code for saving then trying to load right after.

```
        playerGroup = new PlayerGroup();
        playerGroup.n = reqPlayerGroup.n;
        playerGroup.m = reqPlayerGroup.m;
        ofy().save().entity(playerGroup).now();
        response.i = playerGroup;
        PlayerGroup newOne = ofy().load().type(PlayerGroup.class).id(reqPlayerGroup.n).get();
```

But the "newOne" object is null. Even though I just got done saving it. What am I doing wrong?

--Update--
If I try later (like minutes later) sometimes I do see the object, but not right after saving. Does this have to do with the high replication storage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had the same behavior some time ago and asked a question on google groups - objectify

**Here the answer I got :**

```
You are seeing the eventual consistency of the High-Replication 
Datastore.  There has been a lot of discussion of this exact subject 
on the Objecify list in google groups , including several links to the 
Google documentation on the subject. 

Basically, any kind of query which does not include an ancestor() may 
return results from a stale view of the datastore. 

Jeff
```

**I also got another good answer to deal with the behavior**

> For deletes, query for keys and then batch-get the entities. Make sure
>   your gets are set to strong consistency (though I believe this is the
>   default). The batch-get should return null for the deleted entities.
>   When adding, it gets a little trickier. Index updates can take a few
>   seconds. AFAIK, there are three ways out of this: 1; Use precomputed
>   results (avoiding the query entirely). If your next view is the user's
>   recently created entities, keep a list of those keys in the user
>   entity, and update that list when a new entity is created. That list
>   will always be fresh, no query required. Besides avoiding stale
>   indexes, this also speeds up your app. The more you result sets you
>   can reliably manage, the more queries you can avoid.
>
> 2; Hide the latency by "enhancing" the query results with the recently
>   added entities. Depending on the rate at which you're adding entities,
>   either inject only the most recent key, or combine this with the
>   solution in [1](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/objectify-appengine/Daniel/objectify-appengine/icuSeIt97Wg/s7lxSiviL30J).
>
> 3; Hide the latency by taking the user through some unaffected views
>   before landing on your query-based view. This strategy definitely has
>   a smell over it. You need to make sure those extra steps are relevant
>   to the user, or you'll give a poor experience.
>
> Butterflies, Joakim

You can read it all here:

[How come If I dont use async api after I'm deleting an object i still get it in a query that is being done right after the delete or not getting it right after I add one](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/objectify-appengine/Daniel/objectify-appengine/icuSeIt97Wg/s7lxSiviL30J)

---

**Another good answer to a similar question** : [Objectify doesn't store synchronously, even with now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14003248/617373)